# How can I use the async function for my head object in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have to display dynamic meta descriptions for my articles and I am kind of struggling to achieve that with the async function for my head object. This is what I have so far:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component

export default class ArticleContent extends Vue {
  article: any | null = null;
  articlelist = example.data;

  async asyncData({params: any }) { <----- Not sure how I could put in my articlelist here
    return this.articlelist;
  }

  head(): object {
    return {
      title: this.articlelist.productId.productNames['en'],
      meta: [
        {
          hid: this.articlelist._id,
          name: this.articlelist.productNames['en'],
          content: this.articlelist.metaDescription['en'],
        },
      ],
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

`articlelist` is what I am using in the `head()` object for my meta description. Would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0):

Both the `head()` and `asyncData()` properties are not part of the core of vue,

- to use `head()` you need to install [this](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/) as a plugin
- to use `asyncData()` you have to use [nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data)

If your spa has a strong need for seo I suggest you use nuxt, which natively includes seo and the conversion from vue to nuxt is very easy

If you already using nuxt this is the correct way to get

```
async asyncData({params: any }) { 
 const articlelist = await axios.get('some.url'); //get the data
 return { articlelist }; //this object is merged with the data of the istance
```

}